# Connecting simulink/matlab and Ros only work one way, but can't receive messages

Tags: ros, matlab, windows, linux, rosmatlab

I'm trying to connect a Duckiebot with ROS to MATLAB Simulink (unfortunately, I'm compelled to use them), and something strange is happening. I can ping both devices, and I can also send commands from MATLAB to the robot. The problem is that MATLAB/Simulink is not able to receive messages from the robot. I've tried various guides ( like this https://it.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/119559-why-is-the-ros-subscriber-callback-in-matlab-not-triggered-when-messages-are-published-from-an-exter ) on the internet, but it's not working. Do you know how to resolve this issue?
the strange thing is that sometimes (like 1 in 100 tries i can actually read the data, but if i try again i cann't recive anything., and we also tried with the same robot but connected to a macbook with matlab and  it works perfectly, so the problem is windows but i really idk how to do it.

Comment: "It's not working": what do you mean? What have you tried, what errors are present (if any), what is your setup, what behavior are you seeing/not seeing/expecting? As your question is currently written it's hard to answer and we would just be guessing.